# Scheme UpperCase Control

Tags: scheme

I am trying to check whether an element is uppercase or not, but I am having some errors

```
(define (isUpper lst)
  (if (null? (car lst))
  #f
  (if (char-lower-case? (car lst)) #t
           (isUpper (cdr lst)))
  ))
(isUpper '(a s f t r 5 q))
```

Error;
char-lower-case?: expects a char, given 'a

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to be sure: do you want to check if _at least_ one element in a list is an upper-case character, or if _all_ elements are upper-case characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list of characters is actually a list of symbols (and a number). Chars are written with `#\` in front of them:

```
;; In Lisps the custom is to use dashes between words instead of camelCase
(is-upper '(#\a #\s #\f #\t #\r #\5 #\q))
```

The function itself seems to have two problems. 1) The first `if` should check if the whole `lst` is null, rather than checking if the first element is. 2) You should use `char-upper-case?` as the predicate in the inner `if`.

```
(define (is-upper lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      #f
      (if (char-upper-case? (car lst)) 
          #t
          (is-upper (cdr lst)))))
```

Since you have three branches, it would be clearer to use `cond` instead of a nested `if`.

```
(define (is-upper lst)
  (cond
    ((null? lst) #f)
    ((char-upper-case? (car lst)) #t)
    (else (is-upper (cdr lst)))))

(is-upper '(#\a #\b #\c))
;=> #f
(is-upper '(#\a #\B #\c))
;=> #t
```